# Single Page Apps: Visible Flicker When Using Swipe Navigation in Safari OS X

Tags: javascript, safari, single-page-application, pushstate

We have an single page application (built using Backbone) that uses `Backbone.Router` to handle route/URL changes. When a route changes, we typically load some data asynchronously and then render the page. This works well in all browsers, including Safari on OS X, while using the back/forward buttons. In Safari, however, the swipe to navigate backwards or forwards (where the previous page is revealed as you swipe) flickers momentarily between the just navigated to page and the page that was just left.

Given pages A and B, the example flow is:

1. User loads page A
2. User clicks a link to go to page B
3. User swipes back

   1. Page A is revealed while swiping
   2. Page B flickers momentarily after page A has reloaded and rendered its content

The following JS Bin demonstrates the issue: http://jsbin.com/tumeka/1 (edit [here](http://jsbin.com/tumeka/1/edit?html,js) since the route handling messes with JS Bin's edit link). If there is no delay in the route handing, (uncheck the Delay box) then there is no visible issue.

Is this a Safari bug?

Are we doing something wrong?

Is there a workaround?

I've got Safari 6.2 but the issue was originally reported by someone with Safari 7.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: 3 years later, same issue. Did you ever find a solution to this? Thanks!

Comment: have same situation

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68472768/how-can-i-control-disable-the-swipe-snapshot-used-in-ios-for-navigation-purposes