# How can I control/disable the swipe snapshot used in IOS for navigation purposes (JS)

Tags: ios, reactjs, next.js

I've been tasked with fixing a nasty bug in my nextjs application. Essentially, when you navigate around the app on IOS using your fingers to swipe, the content of the page flickers.

As far as I can tell, the browser takes a snapshot of the heap and the dom at a given point in time. Then, once you want to navigate back to that page it shows that snapshot as you're swiping. Once you've finished swiping and the browser has deemed the page is done loading, it stops showing the snapshot and shows the page.

Frankly, I've given up on getting the snapshot to actually match the content once the snapshot stops showing. What I'm looking for is either a way to disable or control the snapshot that gets shown to just be an empty white page. Yes, it hurts UX, but my boss prefers it over the flash.

I've scoured the internet for a solution, and I'm now trying to go through the webkit source for any indication of how I can achieve this. I know for a fact it can be achieved since Instagram has this implemented.

If you go to instagram.com on safari iOS and try to navigate sliding your fingers, you'll see the snapshot is just a white page.

If anybody has any insight as to how this could be done, or at the very least could point me in the right direction, I would truly appreciate it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I was able to solve this by going through the webkit source code.

[Here is the relevant file](https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/blob/main/Source/WebKit/UIProcess/ios/ViewGestureControllerIOS.mm)

Line 225 is what loads the snapshot image. Thus, we need to somehow get the condition in line 224 to evaluate to false. The simplest way I found was to get this piece:

```
shouldRestoreScrollPosition || (currentScrollPosition == snapshot->viewScrollPosition())
```

to evaluate to false. The first part, `shouldRestoreScrollPosition` is determined by the [scrollRestoration property of the history object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/scrollRestoration). The browser support for this property is pretty good, and setting it to manual will get you most of the way to disabling the image snapshot.

There's only one issue, which is the second part of that condition. If the scroll position of the snapshot image and the window are the same, scrollRestoration will be ignored (since it doesn't even need to be applied). I used the following snippet in `_app.tsx` which seems to work okay.

```
    const alternator = React.useRef<number>(0);
    // Scroll slightly and alternate between pages to always invalidate image snapshot.
    // See {redacted} for explanation on this effect and the previous
    React.useEffect(() => {
        const slightScroll = () => {
            if (IOS()) {
                window.scrollTo({left: 0, top: alternator.current});
                alternator.current = Number(!alternator.current);
            }
        };

        router.events.on('routeChangeComplete', slightScroll);

        return () => router.events.off('routeChangeComplete', slightScroll);
    }, []);
```

This is obviously a very next.js specific snippet, but the idea is the same. Alternate between scrolling 1 pixel down or not scrolling to ensure that the scroll position differs when you either go forward or backward in history.

The solution isn't perfect (for example, going between pages that don't have scrolling), but it works well enough. Besides, knowing the exact condition which causes the snapshot image to load/not load means that if anybody that sees this needs to improve on my solution, they can experiment with other ways of getting that condition to evaluate to false or preventing the line from executing farther up (I personally experimented with changing the device-scale header between pages to no avail).

Hope this saves someone the frustration that I had to go through :)

Comment: Hmm.. I am wondering whether this snippet works or not in 2022..?

Comment: @JunsukPark Looking through the linked source code it appears stuff has been moved around, but it should still *somewhat* work

Answer (score 1):

Just make the page transparent before leaving. For example:

```js
window.addEventListener('pagehide', () => {
  document.body.style.opacity = 0
})
```

The snapshot will be transparent, so you'll see nothing when swiping.

Answer (score 0):

I use Vue 3 and faced the same "flashes" on iOS but only if you swipe back (not using nav buttons at the pannel). Then for a fraction of a second you see previous screen.

`pagehide`, `unload` and all other events not fire properly.

I have my router-view wrapped with `<transition>` to make transitions between pages smooth, and that causes this stupid bevahior on safari.

So you need to get rid of the animation, but changing css (either transition name) or setting animation-dureation doesn't help.

**Default code with bug**

```html
<router-view
  v-slot="{ Component }"
  name="template"
>
  <transition
    name="fade"
    mode="out-in"
  >
    <component :is="Component" />
  </transition>
</router-view>
```

So I came up with this:

Instead of using default `<transition>` I created my our wrapper and call there either `<transition>` or dummy `<div>` to make animation instant/fake. I store `transitionWrapper` variable globally and switch it if user swipes back in vue-router. Something like that

**customWrapper**

```html
<template>
  <component :is="wrapperComponent">
    <slot />
  </component>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
import { mapState } from 'pinia'
import { settings } from '@/store'
import Empty from './Empty/index.vue'
import Transition from './Transition/index.vue'

export default defineComponent({
  components: { Empty, Transition },
  data () {
    return {
      page: this.$route.name.toString()
    }
  },

  computed: {
    ...mapState(settings, [
      'transitionWrapper'
    ]),

    wrapperComponent () {
      return this.transitionWrapper === 'div' ? Empty : Transition
    }
  }
})
</script>
```

Here is my modified vue-router, where I change `transitionWrapper` variable and read in `customWrapper`

```html
// settings() is one of my custore store on Pinia. I just import it here
import { settings } from '@/store'

// bla bla routes

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes
})

let navigationInfo = null
router.options.history.listen((to, from, info) => {
  navigationInfo = info
})

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  // detect if swipe back/forward
  if (!navigationInfo?.direction) {
    settings().setTransitionWrapper('transition')
  } else {
    settings().setTransitionWrapper('div')
  }

  // reset for further navigtions
  navigationInfo = null

  //...
  // bla bla next()
})

export default router
```

So when user navigates through normal links/buttons - I render `<transition with animation>`. When user swipes back or press back button - I render `<div>` and no flashes are shown.